# Съезжает отступ блока в Chrome, в IE11 все Ок

Tags: вёрстка, internet-explorer, google-chrome

На сайт 185.47.152.117 (*девелоперский адрес*) потребовалось подставить пару "костылей". В итоге в Chrome в блоке новостей текст новости (дата, заголовок и описание) выравнивается по нижнему краю картинки. В IE11 все Ок, как и предполагалось.

Прошу подсказки, поскольку уже "глаз замылился", похоже. 
`padding-top=0px` (для `.main_news_desc`) ничего не дает. 
Под отладчиком прошли все задействованные стили, поочередно отключая и меняя параметры - эффекта нет.
Что зацепили и чем лечить?
Заранее спасибо!

[image: Для сравнения 2 скриншота, Chrome (с багом) и IE11]

Comment: По указанному адресу нет новостей, что на скриншоте

Comment: Зайди по IP: 185.47.152.117

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте к .main_news_desc

```
vertical-align: top;
```

Если нужно еще сильнее уменьшить верхний отступ, добавьте туда же

```
padding-top: 0;
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! _Не могу поставить оценку, рейтинга не хватает_ :(